# Confused about conditional expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

during my "Intro to probability" Course, I've stumbled upon this simple example:

> Let $X,Y\sim Bin(n,p)$ be independent random variables, Find $\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y=m]$.

I've tried the following (which came out wrong):

$\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y=m] = \mathbb{E}[X|X=m-Y] = m - \mathbb{E}[Y] = m-np$

What am I missing here?
The result should be $\frac m2$, and I'm able to show that in a different way. I'm more interested in understanding the mistake in what I've shown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}[X|X=m-Y] = m - \mathbb{E}[Y]$ is wrong. You are ignoring the fact that you have a conditioning event.

Here is a small trick that gives the answer immediately. Since $\{X,Y\}$ is i.i.d. $E[X|X+Y=m]=E(Y|X+Y=m)$. Hence,  $E[X|X+Y=m]=\frac 1 2 E[X+Y|X+Y=m]=\frac 1  2 m$.

Comment: Thank you,
can you further clarify? I was thinking that:
$\mathbb{E}[X|X=m-Y] = \mathbb{E}[m-Y] = m-\mathbb{E}[Y]$. Because on the condition that X=m-Y I know exactly what X is and I can calculate the expectation directly.

Comment: @Yup8 What you get is $E[m-Y|X=m-Y]$. The conditioning event $X=m-Y$ cannot be ignored. If $m-Y$ was a constant you could have ignored the conditioning but it is not a constant.

Comment: You do know that $X$ equals $m-Y$ *under that condition*, but you what do you expect $Y$ is *under that condition*?